# How to get days between two dates in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying to get the number of days between two dates in google-sheet but sometimes it gives an integer and sometimes it gives another date. How to get only the integer?

Shared public sheet (sheet name DS):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=517697699

## Example

```
SN  COMPANY     AppliedDate     DaysSince   Today
-----------------------------------------------------------
2   McDonald    Feb 17, 2021    54              1   
3   Nielson Feb 17, 2021        Apr 20, 1900    2   **This should be number NOT date
4   Edelman Feb 17, 2021        111             3   
5   Upstart Feb 19, 2021        Apr 18, 1900    1   
6   Root Inc.   Feb 19, 2021    Apr 18, 1900    2
```

## Required

For the column `DaysSince` I would like to have only number. I want number between two dates but sometimes the same formula works sometimes does not work.

Is there any other methods to get number of days between two dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go `Format > Number > Number` to format you entire column. Your problem is that your format is set as `Automatic`.

[image]